# Matching a cell on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, match

I made the code below to match a cell from a cell on another sheet so I can then offset and paste more data where needed.

The code seems to only be able to find the top row of the sheet not the cell with the value.

```vb
Sub Find_select()
  
    Dim matchValue As Variant, FindCell As Long
   
    Sheets("Booking Sheet").Activate
      
    matchValue = Worksheets("Booking Sheet").Range("BE5").Value
    FindCell = WorksheetFunction.Match(matchValue, Worksheets("Data Storage").Range("A2:A10000"), 0)
    
    Sheets("Data Storage").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(FindCell).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum change you would need to do to get the result you want would be this:

`ActiveSheet.Cells(FindCell,1).Select` or `ActiveSheet.Cells(FindCell,"A").Select`

Basically when you use the `.cells` collection you need to specify both the row index and the column index for VBA to understand which cell you are referring to.

This `ActiveSheet.Cells(FindCell)` refers to the first cell of the column whose index is `FindCell`, so for example, if `FindCell=10` then your code would select cell `J1`.

Having said that, I would also avoid using the `.Activate` method and the `ActiveSheet` object when they are not specifically needed and i would use explicit references instead.

```
Dim matchValue As Variant, FindCell As Long
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Booking Sheet")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Storage")

matchValue = sht1.Range("BE5").value
FindCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(matchValue, sht2.Range("A2:A10000"), 0)
sht2.Cells(FindCell, "A").Select
```

Also I'm not sure why you want to use the `.select` method but chances are there's a better way of achieving the same result without it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation really helped! honestly new at writing VBA and have been growing knowledge with little things . I Was using select because i wanted to offset then paste data(it works better with the table I'm making at least this the best way i know at the moment)